# From table format to list

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a table that contains a specimen  ID and a collection date (see image of original excel table). [image: table]

I would like to use R to convert this table into a list that will start with the specimen ID, collection date and location. SO, in this example, the list will start with:

```
4820201  19-04-2021  A1
4820202  19-04-2021  A2
```

I added the dput of the dataframe after I imported it from excel to R:

```
structure(list(...1 = c("Bakje 1a", "Serum 300 ul", "VOCAAL", 
"A", NA, "B", NA, "C", NA, "D", NA, "E", NA, "F", NA, "G", NA, 
"H", NA, NA), ...2 = c("Locatie VK20", "T2 regulier", "1", "4820201", 
"44305", "4820202", "44305", "4820203", "44305", "4820204", "44305", 
"4820206", "44305", "4820207", "44305", "4820208", "44305", NA, 
NA, NA), ...3 = c("Vriezer -80: 3394", NA, "2", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...4 = c("Toren 5", 
NA, "3", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), ...5 = c("Positie in toren: 4", NA, "4", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), ...6 = c(NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...7 = c(NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...8 = c(NA, 
NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), ...9 = c(NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...10 = c(NA, NA, 9, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), ...11 = c(NA, NA, 10, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...12 = c(NA, NA, 11, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    ...13 = c(NA, NA, 12, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...14 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), ...15 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...16 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), ...17 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...18 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), ...19 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...20 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've been mainly trying a lot with using seq along the rows but because the specimen ID and collection date are written on two different cell values, i can't figure out how to tell R that the row with the specimen ID and collection date belong to the same location..

Hope you can help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Another option based in the tidyverse could look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(janitor)

df %>%
  clean_names() %>%
  slice(4:nrow(.)) %>%
  mutate(date = as_date(as.double(lead(x2)), origin = '1899-12-30')) %>%
  unite(list, x2, date, x1, sep = ' ') %>%
  filter(row_number() %% 2 == 1) %>%
  select(list) %>%
  as.list()

# $list
# [1] "4820201 2021-04-19 A" "4820202 2021-04-19 B" "4820203 2021-04-19 C" "4820204 2021-04-19 D" "4820206 2021-04-19 E" "4820207 2021-04-19 F"
# [7] "4820208 2021-04-19 G" "NA NA H"              "NA NA NA"
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this. However, this solution does not account for the exact position in the table, only the row value, which is A. There is also a column value (row 3 in the shared dataframe). the numbers behind the word VOCAAL indicate the column numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is very specific to the data that you have shared.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  slice(-(1:2)) %>%
  select(1:2) %>%
  setNames(.[1, ]) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  fill(VOCAAL) %>%
  group_by(VOCAAL) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = `1`, names_prefix = 'col') %>%
  mutate(col2 = as.Date(as.numeric(col2), origin = '1899-12-30'))
  

#  VOCAAL col1    col2       col3 
#  <chr>  <chr>   <date>     <chr>
#1 A      4820201 2021-04-19 NA   
#2 B      4820202 2021-04-19 NA   
#3 C      4820203 2021-04-19 NA   
#4 D      4820204 2021-04-19 NA   
#5 E      4820206 2021-04-19 NA   
#6 F      4820207 2021-04-19 NA   
#7 G      4820208 2021-04-19 NA   
#8 H      NA      NA         NA
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this. However, this solution does not account for the exact position in the table, only the row value, which is A. There is also a column value (row 3 in the shared dataframe). the numbers behind the word VOCAAL indicate the column numbers